# spinner android with big padding

Tags: java, android, json, spinner, android-arrayadapter

Hello i'm developing an app to android, that use 4 spinners, see the 'pic' below the spinners look like this:

```
____________________
|_option__________v_| spinner 1

____________________
|_option__________v_| spinner 2

____________________
|_option__________v_| spinner 3

____________________
|_option__________v_| spinner 4

(i can't post images)
```

The question is how can i disable the 2 3 4 spinners and set their values to default if the 1 has your value changed ( for default value ), or how i do the same if the 2 spinner has your value changed?

Comment: What you're asking is how you can change the default spinner items which is the first one in your String array, if your other spinner is being used? or what.. please clarify

Comment: sorry not be clear, but imagine, if the user go to spinner 1 and select something, the app will get a JSON and load the content
of spinner 2, and if user go to spinner 2 and select something the will happen the same with spinner 3 and 4,
i want reset to defaults the spinner 2 3 4 if user go to spinner 1 and select his default value, reset to default only the spinner 3 and 4 if user
go to spinner 2 and select his default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your default values are at position 0(first item).

then try following code

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            if (arg2 == 0) {
                spinner2.setSelection(0);
                spinner3.setSelection(0);
                spinner4.setSelection(0);
                spinner2.setEnabled(false);
                spinner3.setEnabled(false);
                spinner4.setEnabled(false);
            }else{
                spinner2.setEnabled(true);
                spinner3.setEnabled(true);
                spinner4.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I will need do the same for all others spinners ? ( repeat the same code only changing the spinner that i want example :
 spinner2.setOn...
 spinner3.setOn... )

Comment: you could create a `OnItemSelectedListener` object and set its `onItemSelected` method, then just assign the same `OnItemSelectedListener` to all the spinners